# How to share a folder between Ubuntu host and a NAT Windows guest with virt-manager?

Tags: networking, virtualization, windows-10, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I have a Windows 10 guest running under a Ubuntu 18.04 host with **Virt-Manager** and KVM. It has NAT connectivity because the host is connected through wi-fi, so I can't access my NAS to share files between guest and host.

I also have installed the [Spice Windows Guest Tools](https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe), but I can drag-drop only small files like text documents or images and not an entire folder. I tried to share a folder from the host adding a filesystem as squash, but the guest is unable to see it.

How can I share big files between the host and the virtual machine?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Install ssh server on guest or host, then use filezilla.

Comment: @Gravemind guest is under NAT.

Comment: My guess is that your host has 192.168.122.xxx IP. So your guest should also have IP from that subnet. You should try 'arp -a' or check network interface settings on Windows to see the IP.

Comment: 192.168.122.xxx is guest IP under KVM NAT. Host IP depends on router and LAN, it could be anything like 192.168.yyy.xxx.

Comment: actually it depends on your communication. Be default KVM creates **virbr0** interface on your Linux host which has 192.168.122.1 IP. So if you want to connect to host from guest you can do ssh login@192.168.122.1 (of course it works only if you have ssh server seted up on Host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved installing the **SMB networking protocol** with [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) on the host Ubuntu machine.

On the **Win10 guest** machine, I created a `'Public'` folder with the appropriate permissions and shared it on the network with the following network path: `\\<vm-guest-name>\Public`.

On the **Ubuntu Linux** host machine, I used the `'Connect to server'` function and set the following address as a reference: `smb://<IP-address-vm-guest>/Public`. In my case, the address was `192.168.122.188`.

In the end, I saved the address with the SMB protocol as a bookmark on Nautilus. Now, with a simple click, I can access the shared folder between the host and the virtual machine, and move files of any size.

Comment: The opposite should also work. Share the `Public` folder in your Ubuntu home using SMB and open it in Windows guest.